# Beautifulsoup error on import

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm getting the following error when I try to import beautifulsoup:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_first_simple_script.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

I try to import it the following way:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

My python version is 3.6.1, and beautifulsoup is: 'beautifulsoup4==4.6.0'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you install beautifulsoup? Are you sure it is in the same virtualenv as the python 3.6.1 install?

Comment: Run the commands `which pip` (or pip3), `which python` (or which python3), and `pip freeze` (or pip3 freeze), and post the results here.

Comment: I used the command: pip install BeautifulSoup4. I found that pip3 should be used instead of pip for python3 or above, so I did it but it didn't work. I got it to work when I first uninstalled beautifulsoup with pip uninstall BeautifulSoup4, and then installing it again with pip3 install BeautifulSoup4 command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the command: pip install BeautifulSoup4. I found that pip3 should be used instead of pip for python3 or above, so I did it but it didn't work. I got it to work when I first uninstalled beautifulsoup with pip uninstall BeautifulSoup4, and then installing it again with pip3 install BeautifulSoup4 command.